# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

So I had to explain to someone about limits and I got asked: how do you prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=0$ without intuition.

After a while I answered:

Let's construct a sequence $(a_n)$ where $a_n=\frac1n$(the sequence starts from $n=1$) now, $\left[\frac1x\right]'=-\frac1{x^2}$ thus $a_n>a_{n+1}$.

Now let's assume that there is a value, say $k$, such that $a_n>k>0,\forall n\in\Bbb Z^+$.

If $k$ is a rational number then $k=\frac qp\ge\frac1p=a_p>a_{p+1}$ which is contradiction

If $k$ is irrational then: $k=\cdots +b_2+b_1+b_0+b_{-1}+b_{-2}+\cdots$ where $b_i=c\times 10^i, c\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$. Now I can construct a number $k'=\max\{\,b_i\ne0\}$. $k'$ is rational, hence $k>k'=\frac qp\ge\frac1p=a_p>a_{p+1}$ which is contradiction.

This implies that there is no $k$ such that $a_n>k>0,\forall n\in\Bbb Z^+$ which implies that $\inf\{a_n\}=0$ and because $a_n>a_{n+1}$ I also know that  $\inf\{a_n\}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x$ hence $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=0$.

My question is, is my proof okay? I don't think that I have any problems but I am not completely sure. And if yes. Is there a easier way to prove that for any positive irrational number there is always smaller positive rational number?

Comment: Btw, I'm well aware about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205010/proof-of-1-x-as-x-approaches-infinity-equals-0

Comment: Do you really mean "without intuition" ? I would have expected the converse. Without intuition, you apply the formal definition of a limit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust no, without intuition means a formal proof, the reason I have this question and not just using the way of the formal definition is because the one that asked me this is not at that level yet

Comment: @Holo This seems quite a cute proof. Did you come up with it, on your own?

Comment: I think your argumetns already imply an intuition about the limit, Why else would you try that? In case you have no intuition about the limit, then I would reccomend to first do some numerics to get the limit

Comment: @bat_of_doom thanks you, yes I came up with it on my own

Comment: "Is there a easier way to prove that for any positive irrational number there is always smaller positive rational number?": $\forall\ 0<q,0<q/2<q$.

Comment: Sorry but in my opinion, your proof is much harder than that with the mere definition of a limit, and it invokes more advanced concepts, such as a derivative !

Comment: @YvesDaoust Which is actually not needed, since n+1 > n, is true.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think it has a lot to the fact you already know and(I assume) worked with the definition, for someone completely new to this I think this is easier. But I may be wrong

Comment: @bat_of_doom: of course. (By the way, not all rationals end in all zeroes.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust but if $q$ is irrational $q/2$ is also irrational. I'm looking for smaller rational

Comment: @holo: take $1/\lceil1/q\rceil$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to prove that there exists no $k>0$ such that $$a_n>k>0 \; \forall n \in \mathbb N$$

So, you can choose $$n=\left\lfloor \frac k2 \right \rfloor +1$$

Since, $$n = \left\lfloor \frac k2 \right \rfloor +1 > \frac k2  \implies a_n = \frac{1}{n}< \frac k2 <k $$

This leads to contradiction, and hence we're done.

Answer (score 2):

you can prove directly by the definition, if you fix $$M>0$$ you can always find a value $\epsilon >0$ $$x=0+\epsilon$$ such that $$\frac {1}{x} > M$$ infact it is sufficient to select $$\epsilon < \frac {1}{M}$$

Comment: The problem is that the one asked me that is not at a level he learned the formal definition of limit

Comment: ok you can explain in this way as it was a game: tell your friend to fix a number as big as he can, then you choose $\epsilon$ such that $1/\epsilon$ is grater than M, with the good choice you always win, then the limit is $+\infty$

Comment: @gimusi you are using the Archimedean property without justifying it, because note that M is an integer.

Comment: @bat_of_doom sorry I can't get your point about the Archimedean property

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall\ \epsilon>0:\forall\ x>\frac1\epsilon:\left|\frac1x-0\right|<\epsilon.$$

This proves constructively that

$$\forall\ \epsilon>0:\exists X:\forall\ x>X:\left|\frac1x-0\right|<\epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Show::

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{1}{x}  = 0.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $M > 1/\epsilon$ , $M,$  real.

Then :

For $x > M:$

$|\dfrac {1}{x}| < 1/M < \epsilon.$